# docker wsl2 linux like path for mapped folders are missing

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm searching for more than two days and unfortunately, none of the solutions worked so far.

I want to know where the mapped folder is

let say

```
$host> docker run -ti -v /home:/home2 continuumio/anaconda3 bin/bash

$root@9fce1cb15cae> cd /home2
$root@9fce1cb15cae: /home2# ls
$root@9fce1cb15cae: /home2# touch test.txt
$root@9fce1cb15cae: /home2# ls
test.txt
```

now if I come out of the container, and search for `test.txt` I can't find it anywhere

if I look into the wsl folder I have these two distro

[image]

and if I run the `wsl -l` I get this

```
└ $ wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop (Default)
docker-desktop-data
```

so I'm assuming the mapping should be available inside the `docker-desktop` as it's the default

if I run `wsl ls /home` I get empty result

the `docker-desktop-data` doesn't have a `home` folder to begin with
[image: docker-desktop-data doesn't have mapping]

if inside my windows I query for `/home` there isn't such folder
[image: docker source folder isn't available]

if I look for the docker volume, there isn't any volume available
[image: docker volume is empty]

and if I inspect the mounted volume

[image: mapping doesn't show anything useful]

so in summary

- there is no local folder in my windows named `home`
- the `docker-desktop` home folder is empty
- the `docker-desktop-data` doesn't have any `home` folder
- in drive `C:` I don't have any home folder

so my big question is where is the mapped folder?

interestingly if I write a windows path as the mapping, the mapping works quite well

```
$host> docker run -ti -v c:\users\me\repo\testing-docker:/home2 continuumio/anaconda3 bin/bash

$root@9fce1cb15cae> cd /home2
$root@9fce1cb15cae: /home2# ls
$root@9fce1cb15cae: /home2# touch test.txt
$root@9fce1cb15cae: /home2# ls
test.txt
```

if I go to the `testing-docker` I can see `test.txt`

so magically if I write a **windows path**, it works well, but as long as it's a **linux path** it map it to somewhere that I don't know and I can't find it. it doesn't throw any errors. if I remap the `/home` to another container, I can see the `test.txt` is there. so I'm sure the file is somewhere, but I don't know where. so the question is where it is get mapped, where it could be that isn't inside the wsl? I tried all the folder that mentioned in other SO answers, but none of them worked for me

I'm using `Docker version 20.10.20, build 9fdeb9c`